# Adobe Animate CC- Animation only working in Animate, not browsers

Tags: javascript, html, animation, dreamweaver

I created a simple text animation in Animate CC. I publish (including JavaScript/HTML and OAM), then go to Dreamweaver CC to insert it. It actually plays in the DW's preview (incorrectly, but it plays). However, it will not play at all in Firefox, IE or Chrome. Where do I need to start looking for an answer? Export differently or what? All software is current. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: control+shift+i on Chrome, look for the console tab. IF there is some messages in red it means that you are getting an error.

Comment: It gives me a "file not found" error.  When it publishes, it includes an html, .js and .oam file in the same folder.

Comment: The 404 (not found) is pertaining to another element on the page so I am not getting an error for the animation. I don't know why it would work in DW and not any browser. Anyone have any insight?

Comment: I don't know the extension .oam, but I assume that's the actual video, if so, you may need to export the video to some generic video extension such as .MP4; the extension .oam could be specific to the Adobe CC range, therefore a browser may not understand it yet.